# Zoiper Softphone get register with Random IP instead of Local Network IP with Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, pjsip

I am new to Asterisk. And trying to setup basic PBX, with 2 zoiper softphones.

here is my pjsip configuration:

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=192.168.100.12
local_net=192.168.100.0/24

;Templates for the necessary config sections

[endpoint_internal](!)
type=endpoint
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[auth_userpass](!)
type=auth
auth_type=userpass

[aor_dynamic](!)
type=aor
max_contacts=1
remove_existing=yes

;Definitions for our phones, using the templates above

[demo-alice](endpoint_internal)
auth=demo-alice
aors=demo-alice
[demo-alice](auth_userpass)
password=pass123
username=demo-alice
[demo-alice](aor_dynamic)

[demo-bob](endpoint_internal)
auth=demo-bob
aors=demo-bob
rtp_symmetric=no
force_rport=no
rewrite_contact=no
[demo-bob](auth_userpass)
password=pass123
username=demo-bob
[demo-bob](aor_dynamic)


[demo-deepak](endpoint_internal)
auth=demo-deepak
aors=demo-deepak
rtp_symmetric=no
force_rport=no
rewrite_contact=no
[demo-deepak](auth_userpass)
password=pass123
username=demo-deepak
[demo-deepak](aor_dynamic)
```

I have Zoiper softphone installed at IP: 192.168.100.16. while registering it get registered with Ip 43.224.158.252

below if the asterisk cli message

```
 -- Added contact 'sip:demo-deepak@43.224.158.252:55640;transport=UDP;rinstance=46b5f1e7b0cf811a' to AOR 'demo-deepak' with expiration of 60 seconds
  == Endpoint demo-deepak is now Reachable
```

**PS**: - Entire setup was done with WiFi router with no Internet connectivity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoiper know asterisk's IAX2 protocol, use it.

Other option is use internal asterisk's ip on zoiper and disable STUN/TURN support

http://prntscr.com/r6af7c